# Bootstrap datetimepicker gives same date everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a bootstrap datetimepicker. Looks like there is an issue (Or maybe I'm not doing something right). I get the **same** date/time even though I modify my datepicker.

I'm using this plugin:

> bootstrap-datetimepicker
>   https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

This is my datepicker code:

```
initializeDatePickers : function(){
var $datetimepicker = $(this.el).find('#datetimepicker');
$datetimepicker.datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    defaultDate: new Date(),
});
},


<!-- HTML code -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="datetimepicker">Start From</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
            <input type="text" name="startFrom" class="form-control" required data-error="select date and time" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I get the data using the following code:

```
var data = $('#scheduleForm').serializeArray();
var schedule = {'startFrom': this.fetchData(data, 'startFrom')};
```

**Problem:**

**When I select bootstrap datepicker for the first time it prints out the defaultTime. Let's say I make a change, it STILL prints the old time.
Am I missing something?**

Comment: We really need more information to figure out what's happening. E.g, which datetimepicker are you using? There are a lot of forks of it on GitHub... Who's `fetchData()` and where's its code? Please, update with more...

Comment: I believe it's this: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate

Comment: Still cannot reproduce, could you please upgrade your post with as much code as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out the problem of your code. Your js is not enough.

But I made an example. It seems works.

```js
$(function() {
  var $datetimepicker = $('#datetimepicker');
  $datetimepicker.datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    defaultDate: new Date()
  });
  $datetimepicker.on('dp.change', function() {
    console.log($(this).data("DateTimePicker").date());
    //var data = $('#scheduleForm').serializeArray();
    //console.log(data);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id='test-form'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetimepicker">Start From</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" name="startFrom" class="form-control" required data-error="select date and time" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much. I was missing $datetimepicker.on('dp.change', function() { which is the reason I always get old value